# how do i remove the collapse/expand control from the module container

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I am new in DNN and can you please help me provide the steps in order to remove the collapse/expain control from the containers. I am creating a skin and i want to get rid of that control.

Answer (score 2):

That control is part of the container.  There is a Containers folder inside of each Portals folder, and that's where you'll find the controls for the containers.  You'll want to remove the Visibility control from the container.

Comment: Dukes 
thank you for replying. I am aware of that fact. However we are trying to implement a feature and would like to utilize as much space as possible. Removing the expand/collapse button does not do any good as i still see a gap as tall as a line height. However if i view the page in firefox there is no gap. the gap dissapears. Can you please advise on how do i remove the gap. Example, i have a simple module and below the heading of the module, there is a text displayed "Hover here, then click toolbar to edit content". this text shows up below the collapse expand button.

Comment: I am writing here again as i had limitation of text in the mesage...contd....
by removing the button, this text does not move up and eliminates the extra white space. Can you please advise.
thanks

Comment: That sounds like an issue with your container's CSS styling.  I'd try to examine the space using IE's developer tools and FireBug to see if you find what style you could change to remove that space.  It might be good to edit this question or add a new question with more details about the markup and styles that you're seeing (including a link to a site using this container, or at least the markup you're seeing).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `Collapse/Expand` button from the module setting by choosing `None` in the `Page Settings` tab for the `Collapse/Expand` feature